# echo 1 > sudo /sys/block/sdX/device/delete command

Tags: unix, scsi

i am trying to delete a scsi disk using below command
"echo 1 > sudo /sys/block/sdb/device/delete"
when i try to lsscsi after the command,i am still able to see the disk.

That would be great if some one can point where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that this question should be moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: ok will move question to those pages,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /path/to/file
```

---

The command `echo 1 >sudo` actually create a file named `sudo`

Comment: Or `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /path/to/file"`, which avoids unnecessarily echoing `1` back to the console.